# Is it possible to fix number of sectors in the USB enclosure?

Tags: partitioning, usb-storage, partition-recovery, luks, sectors

I have a LUKS-encrypted external USB hard drive (1TB HGST Touro S). If I put the drive into the new USB enclosure, it reduces the number of sectors by 1 and I cannot mount the filesystem anymore.

Is there a way to fix it without reformatting of HDD?

In the old USB enclosure:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd

Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe8070000

Disk /dev/sdd doesn't contain a valid partition table    

sudo fdisk -l /dev/mapper/touros_old

Disk /dev/mapper/touros_old: 1000.2 GB, 1000202788864 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953521072 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/touros_old doesn't contain a valid partition table

sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/mapper/touros_old 

 e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
 /dev/mapper/touros_old: clean, 450506/61054976 files, 208726295/244190134 blocks
```

Now if I change the hard drive to the new USB enclosure, the following happens:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204885504 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525167 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe8070000

Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table

sudo fdisk -l /dev/mapper/touros_old

Disk /dev/mapper/touros_old: 1000.2 GB, 1000202788352 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953521071 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/touros_old doesn't contain a valid partition table

sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/mapper/touros_old 

e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 244190134 blocks
The physical size of the device is 244190133 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort<y>? yes
```

Comment: Is there anything special about the "new USB enclosure" you're using?

Comment: no, just bought it online recently. Interestingly, my problem is kind of solved now, since I had one more HDD. Let's say HDD2 in enclosure B; and my original HDD1 was in enclosure A. Putting it to enclosure C did not work, but after I put HDD2 in enclosure C and HDD1 in enclosure B, everything works.